# Gurobi - Infeasible Constraint

Tags: constraints, gurobi, pypsa

```
start_time = time.time()
hours = 5
for i in range(hours):
print('---Running hour, ', i)
fsthr = i+35
lsthr = i + 1+ 35
network.lopf(network.snapshots[fsthr:lsthr], solver_name='gurobi', pyomo=False)                                                                                             
n=gp.Model('snapshot')
```

I am running an OPF model for the US for the year 2022. I had used 2022 actual data to get an idea. When i try to run the model, i get

WARNING:pypsa.linopf:Optimization failed with status warning and termination condition infeasible or unbounded.

How can i check what the constraint is?

Answer (score 2):

With gurobi, you can also run

```py
n.model.compute_set_of_infeasible_constraints()
```

after solving.

(This only works with the new solver interface n.optimize(), not n.lopf())

Answer (score 0):

You can check the constraints of the network created by calling `network.model.constraints` and if you want the objective function you can call `network.model.objective`.